# How to update Python on a Mac with Unix commands

Tags: terminal, snow-leopard, install, unix, python

After giving up on doing a disk partition and getting Linux, I decided to try and install Python 3.3.2 on a 32 bit Intel Core 2 Duo iMac with OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. I did pretty much everything the [official website](http://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) says, but it isn't working at all.

First of all, I downloaded the installer for Mac OS X 6 and later, which should supposedly put a folder called MacPython 3.3 with IDLE, PythonLauncher and a Build Applet tool in my Applications folder. What I have instead is a folder called Python 3.3 which does contain (aside from the documentation and a command to update shell profile) IDLE and PythonLauncher, but no Build Applet tool; I typed 'python' into my Terminal window to see if 3.3.2 was installed, but it said Python 2.6.1 even after restarting my computer. The ReadMe in the disk image that contains the installer says running the installer should also 'put the underlying machinery into the folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework'. I did every search imaginable and apparently there is no such folder anywhere in my hard drive.

Basically, I want to install 3.3.2 and run things in programme mode rather than shell mode, which I find to be a huge pain in the bottom. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** found the Frameworks folder. Python.framework contains 4 folders named 2.3, 2.5, 2.6 and Current, which has several other folders inside – all for Python 2.6. The official page says I shouldn't delete any of them because they already come with Mac. How do I put 3.3 here?

Comment: What is programme mode and shell mode?

Comment: You have not found the Frameworks folder - the one you have found is /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ which is the Apple installed one the one you want is as the notes say under /Library - How are you looking for the path

Comment: According to the guide I'm reading, there are 2 ways to run Python applications, which are programme mode (as standalone applications) and shell mode (by typing commands one by one into the Python shell).

Comment: what guide can you give a URL (also looking at my install looks like Build Applet is a python 2 thing - I don't have it either

Comment: Oh, there I found /Library. I figured it had to be /System/Library since the /Library in my home folder didn't have any frameworks, but turns out there's a third one with Python 3.3.2. Thanks!

Comment: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/GeneralIntro/introduction.html#the-python-programming-language This is the guide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not really help anyone else. The actual problems is lack of knowledge of Unix command and use of path as the python docs are correct

Comment: Changed tags and title, hope it's more appropriate now.

Comment: @Mark - We've retired the "too narrow" and "useful to others" clauses for off-topic questions. All that remains is if it's a practical (for even one person) and relates to using Apple hardware or software. This might be very narrow - but it looks fine in terms of scope and specificity to me,

Answer (score 1):

So your Mac is still looking for an old version of Python. You need to inform it that there is in fact a new version and where it can find it. To do this, you need to update the `PATH` to Python.

This can be done in your `.bash_profile` file.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.3.2.
# The original version is saved in .profile.pysave.
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

After you update the `.bash_profile` file Terminal should run the new version of Python, when you ask for it.

Comment: Easier to use /usr/local/bin as the path

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you tell me how to access the .bash_profile file? I tried searching for it and I couldn't find it.

Comment: It does not exist by default - I would go and read a Unix tutorial to understand some shell programming

Comment: Ok, I understand some more about Unix now and I get what .bash_profile does. However, when I run the cat command on it I get exactly what IdeoREX posted – but if I type `python` I get 2.6.1. Should I move the file to another directory? It's in my home directory right now.