# How to install specific version of python on OS X

Tags: homebrew, python

I need to install python3.4 on my OS X. 
Tried to do it with `brew install python3` and now I have python 3.5.1. But I need py3.4.

How can I install python3.4 on my Mac?

Comment: Maybe from: [https://www.python.org/ftp/python/](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have done this sort of thing in two ways - however both do not coexist with homebrew although I suspect there should be a way similar to the macports one.

### General package manager

The first is using [Macports](https://www.macports.org) as the package manager. There are separate ports for several python versions 2.x and 3.x currently 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 3.4 and 3.5. For example to install 3.4 do `sudo port install python34` There is also a python_select port that running it allows you to choose which version of python is run by /opt/bin/python. e,g, to select macports python 2.7 `port select --set python  python27`

Each package manager needs to run as the only package manager otherwise it will be confused with unexpected different versions of libraries and executables on its paths.

From comments the similar homebrew way is given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/151019 Short answer seems to be `brew switch` the equivalent to port_select

### Python version managers

The other way is install direct from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) This will install a python into /usr/local/bin I think this installs a python and python3 executable.  The issue with Homebrew is that it assumes that things in /usr/local are installed by it and so brew doctor will report these python.org pythons and libraries as issues and as this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178621/homebrew-says-my-python-installation-could-cause-issues-and-im-not-sure-what-to?rq=1) shows also the frameworks in /Library will be problematic.

EDIT 8/2018 *** I would now suggest using [conda](https://conda.io/docs/) either miniconda or anaconda. This is another package manager but based and mainly meant for python, it also gives the equivalent of python's virtual environments and pyenv (as per other [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/319675/237)) and so each project can be in a different python and different libraries (Macports only switches python version for all projects)

Comment: It is easiy with brew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: @Raz that is how to install one or the other not install both and chnage between them - or else I misunderstand the answer - if it is simple please give as an answer - hopefully in a simple way

Comment: @Mark I needed to run my project on the specific python version and google gives this answer. Since brew is mentioned in the question I would prefer to install additional python version than additional package manager. My comment was for googlers like me.

Answer (score 107):

For Python in macOS, use `pyenv`:

```
brew install pyenv
```

To install a specific Python version, run:

```
pyenv install <version>
```

To select a version for every command run with the current folder:

```
pyenv local 3.5.0
```

*Note that you must update `PATH` in your environment to find pyenv's `python3` before any other:*

```
PATH="~/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
```

With recent version of OSX(13.X) the path is moved to /etc/paths.d/
Add a file eg: pyenvpath to /etc/paths.d/pyenvpath
Add the path to that file.

To list available versions:

```
pyenv versions
```

See https://gist.github.com/Bouke/11261620 for more information.

Comment: I use this installed python 3.6.6rc1 but brew still points python3 to 3.7.0.  Since I'm using Heroku and Pipfile use 3.6, I use the other answer to get 3.6.5 installed (3.6.6 isn't available in GitHub, as far as I can tell).

Comment: This didn't work for me for installing current beta (3.10 right now); I ended up using git clone to get the source code, switching to 3.10 branch: `git checkout 3.10`; and configuring and building per https://devguide.python.org/setup/#compile-and-build .

Comment: does brew install python install it for all folders on Mac os,  or just the specific folder you run the command in?

Comment: `pyenv` doesn't work on any major version of 3.5 on Mac OS for me. Issue is the same as: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1768

Answer (score 57):

`$ brew install python3`
is equals follow

`$ brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb`

So. if you want to install a specific version then, you must check before install.

- Check the git history of [python.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/python.rb)
- Find the version you want. Now you can use `brew install` with the corresponding commit hash:

  - 3.4.3_2: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/bd43f59bd50bb49242259f327cb6ac7a8dd59478/Formula/python3.rb`
  - 3.5.2_3: `$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/ec545d45d4512ace3570782283df4ecda6bb0044/Formula/python3.rb`
  - 3.6.5_1: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`

There is also: https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python where you can install using `brew install sashkab/python/python34` and `brew link python34 --force`

*Please note that python3.rb was renamed to python.rb at some point. Change the URL if necessary.*

Comment: As an FYI: Python 3.4.3_2 is `$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/bd43f59bd50bb49242259f327cb6ac7a8dd59478/Formula/python3.rb` and then `python3.4 -V` should work.

Comment: @iwasrobbed it's 404: Not Found at this moment

Comment: This didn't install pip3. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the browser page for the Python 3 formula will not display.  It says something about the history being too long and taking too long to generate on the page.  I was tempted, but did not, clone the entire repo.

Comment: The file `python3.rb` is renamed as `python.rb` already.  Try the other path.

As FYI: Python 3.6.5_1 is `$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`

Comment: 3.7.6 is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/9b35174928/Formula/python.rb`

Comment: @Kirby you need to install pip3 additionally as it is not part of main python3

Comment: @MikeWilliamson just clone the repo and do a ```git log master -- Formula/python.rb```to see all versions.

Comment: `Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of python@3.7 formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract' or 'brew create' and 'brew tap-new' to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):`

Comment: so, its 2021...and they wont let us do this anymore
Invalid usage: Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract python` to a stable tap on GitHub instead. (UsageError)

Answer (score 30):

1. Install the required version:

   ```
    % brew install python@3.7
    % brew list | grep python
    % brew ls python@3.7
    % ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.8_1/bin/python3.7
   ```
2. Add a soft link to /usr/local/bin/:

   ```
    % ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.8_1/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7
    % python3.7 -V
   ```
3. Create a Python virtual environment:

   ```
    % python3.7 -m venv venv37
   ```
4. Enter the virtual environment:

   ```
    % source venv37/bin/activate
   ```
5. Exit the virtual environment:

   ```
    % deactivate
   ```

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a much easier approach *AND* keeps away from /usr/local/bin !!

https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python

I haven't tested it, but it promises to be able to install any version (and multiple versions) of Python.

Including 3.6.6 which isn't available in the brew core as far as I can tell.